# Woocommerce product stars how to show in shop page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I want to show the number of reviews and average star ratings of a product in Shop/ Product Archive pages. Currently this is shown in single product pages. But I want it in all-products page. How can I achieve that? Please help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can put this into your theme **functions.php** file:

To show the **average star ratings** of a product in **Shop/ Product Archive pages** -

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'add_star_rating' );
function add_star_rating()
{
global $woocommerce, $product;
$average = $product->get_average_rating();

echo '<div class="star-rating"><span style="width:'.( ( $average / 5 ) * 100 ) . '%"><strong itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</strong> '.__( 'out of 5', 'woocommerce' ).'</span></div>';
}
```

Comment: thanks Swapnali, i tried in child theme, but nothing worked. I tried already this method. It not worked at all any shop loop page.

Comment: Thanks, now it showing. I thought earlier history or cache issue. Thanks